# WooCommerce booking error: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

Does anyone know a fix for this WordPress error message on my website from the WooCommerce Booking plugin I tried activating:

```
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'WC_dokuonecheckout_Gateway' does not have a method 'check_dokuonecheckout_response' in /home1/tongamar/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324
```

Comment: Bookings is a premium plugin (well the one I am thinking of is) and you should contact their support. Your error suggests that the `WC_dokuonecheckout_Gateway` class is missing the `check_dokuonecheckout_response` that some `add_hook|filter` is expecting to find.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.